# Что означает eslint-disable-next-line?

Tags: javascript

Потребовалось подключить библиотеку **Mansonry** в **js**. Согласно документации, нужно создать объект. Как только вставляю этот код в своей проект, в консоли появляется ошибка:

> 'Masonry' is not defined no-undef
>   Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Погуглив, нашел способ решения. Необходимо перед созданием объекта добавить комментарий `//eslint-disable-next-line` 
Так и сделал. Всё заработало.

**Подскажите**, почему так и что означает этот комментарий?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> //eslint-disable-next-line
> ```

Отключает проверку eslint'ом всех правил в следующей строке.

> 'Masonry' is not defined no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Чтобы не было этой ошибки, надо в список разрешённых глобальных переменных добавить `Masonry`: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals